# Обрезка строк разной длины

Tags: php

В проекте есть имена и фамилии пользователей, мне надо выводить их в таком формате:

```
Игорь С.
Алексей М.
Евгений Я.
Анджела В.
```

Подскажите, как мне их правильно обрезать фамилии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обрезайте фамилии пользователей с помощью следующего кода:

```
$last_name = mb_substr($last_name, 0, 1, 'utf-8').".";
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе чувак!